# Where are the permissions for adding user applications?

Tags: gitlab

We have a self-hosted gitlab solution and are trying to integrate a third-party application. For that we created a new account and wanted to set up a new application. But we were greeted by the following screen:

[image: Application view]

> 'Adding new applications is disabled in your GitLab instance. Please
>   contact your Gitlab administrator to get the permission'

I have an admin account and have looked everywhere to set this permission but can't find it. In my own account it is also impossible to add application, but in the admin area the possibility is there.

In the pricing table there does not seem to be any option that adds this feature so I don't think it is a blocked feature.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Great question: fun-fact: this just did work in the past (for testing I still have two applications in my own user account, however as of today I can not create more integrations anymore as user but only with my admin account)

Answer (score 1):

- Go to https://gitlab.example.com/admin/application_settings
- On the general tab beneath "Account and limit", there is a checkbox called "User OAuth applications".
- Once you toggle this every user gets the ability to define her or his own OAuth2 Applications.